# jQuery validate submit button class

Tags: jquery, validation

I am trying to validate form and give a submit button a class if form isnt valid. In default [jQuery validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) just will give a `.error` class to all inputs except the submit button. Is it posible to add a error class to my submit button (`#submit`) if form isnt valide? And remove the class if form is valide?

My html:

```
<form id="sub" action="index.html"  method="post">
    <input class="required" name="email" placeholder="Your mail here" type="text">
    <input id="submit" name="submit" value="SEND" type="submit">
</form>
```

JS:

```
      <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sub").validate();
  });

</script>
```

P.S The class also can be attached to form#sub element, if it is easier.

Comment: You should look into the plugin documentation, how to get the current status after validating the form. If it doesn't validate, add the `.error`-class to the button manually: `$( '#sub [type="submit"]' ).addClass( 'error' );`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this (from the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions)):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#sub").validate({
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                $(form).find("input:submit").removeClass("error");
                form.submit();
            },
            invalidHandler: function(form) {
                $(form).find("input:submit").addClass("error");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods which handled when form is valid or not invalidHandler and submitHandler.

You can put the jQuery code to add or remove error class on submit button in them.

**Example:**

```
$("#sub").validate({
   invalidHandler: function(){
      $("#sub input:submit").addClass("error");
   },
   submitHandler: function(){
      $("#sub input:submit").removeClass("error");
   }
});
```

Hope this will help !!